# Unreadable thread name in logs with Logback

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-logback

I run Spring Boot application and have following **logback-spring.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %black(%d{ISO8601}) %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.}): %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/logger.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/archived/logger-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Default Spring Boot logs works fine:

```
2020-07-06 10:24:02,276 INFO  [restartedMain] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

But when app tries to log incoming information, I'll get:

```
2020-07-06 10:24:24,604 INFO  [Áèáëèîòåêà èãð Google Play Telegram Executor] ru.miroha.bot.GooglePlayGameBot: Hello, Test!
```

Same in the console and a file.

`Google Play Telegram Executor` is legit, but what is `Áèáëèîòåêà èãð` it?

If I'll remove this logback.xml configuration and run with default Spring Bot logger this message will look like:

```
2020-07-06 10:22:00.418  INFO 6796 --- [legram Executor] ru.miroha.bot.GooglePlayGameBot          : Hello!
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the real problem. This thread name contains my telegram bot name (api features I guess), and this api cannot correctly process the cyrillic alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

The encoded text is coming from `%C{1.}` in your config. Maybe the caller of your object has classnames intentionally obfuscated? Is the class invoking that row from a library?

Do you need that depth of caller loging?caller that you want to be logging as opposed to `%C{0}`?

More on caller logging:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html

Comment: Seems like it's not even a wrong logback configuration. I've just checked the thread name with `java.lang.Thread` and it returned `Áèáëèîòåêà èãð Google Play Telegram Executor`. Interesting.

Comment: yeah the `%C` you have in the Pattern is logging the callers and one of the caller classes contains text that isn't decoding properly. The configuration is valid but it is just the callers on the stack that aren't going to show the way you want.